# How do I solve this confusing Function problem?

Tags: calculus, functions

So I'm not sure what this kind of problem is called, but I am in my fist semester of Calculus and I am really confused. Here is the actual problem:

A function *f* is given that satisfies

$$f(\frac{1}{x + 1}) = 2x - 12$$

for all real numbers *x*.

The first question states:

Compute the following quantities:

(a) *f(1)*

The way I tried solving this was by doing:

$$f(\frac{1}{(1) + 1}) = 2x - 12$$
$$f(\frac{1}{2}) = 2x - 12$$
$$f(\frac{1}{2}) = 2\frac{1}{2} - 12$$
$$f(\frac{1}{2}) = -9\frac{1}{2}$$

I really don't know if I am correct and my TA has been no help. They don't give us the answers because they don't want us to cheat. I really need some help with this, I'm riding the struggle bus today =)

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Jossie: Are you sure?

Comment: @copper.hat Certainly that is irrelevant.

Comment: @copper.hat The formula above doesn't define $f$ at the origin.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: I see, I'm not sure why I was so concerned with it...

Comment: Substituting $x=1$ in the left hand side and then two lines further substituting $x=\frac12$ in the right hand side is not a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find $x$ such that $$\frac{1}{1+x}=1$$

Do you see why? Think about it this way. Usually, we're given that $f(x)=\text{ blah }$, so whenever we want to know what $f$ evaluates at $x$, we just plug in $x$ in our formula, and we're done. But here, you're being told something slightly different: you can think now that you're being given a new *dependent* variable $w=\dfrac{1}{1+x}$, and you're being told that $$f(w)=2x-12$$

Now, if you want to know what $f(0)$ is, you want to find $x$ that makes $w=0$, and then you're free to go. It turns out, we may solve $w$ in terms of $x$, indeed: $$\begin{align}
  w &=& \frac{1}{{1 + x}} \cr 
  w\left( {1 + x} \right) &=& 1 \cr 
  w + wx &=& 1 \cr 
  wx &=& 1 - w \cr 
  x &=& \frac{{1 - w}}{w} \end{align} $$

And observe that for *any* value I give you, call it $y$, we can solve $y=w $ by saying that $$x= \frac{{1 - y}}{y}$$

To wit, if we plug $x= \dfrac{{1 - y}}{y}$ in $w=\dfrac{1}{1+x}$, we get $$  \frac{1}{{1 + \frac{{1 - y}}{y}}} = \frac{1}{{\frac{y}{y} + \frac{{1 - y}}{y}}} = \frac{1}{{\frac{{y + 1 - y}}{y}}} = \frac{1}{{\frac{1}{y}}} = y$$

For example, if we want to solve $w=\dfrac 1 {10}$, then by our finding $$x = \frac{1}{{1/10}} - 1 = 10 - 1 = 9$$

and you can surely check that $$\frac{1}{1+9}=\frac 1 {10}$$

The whole point to this is we have found a *general rule* that solves the equation $$y=\frac{1}{1+x}$$

Since, as you can see, this rule *reverses* what  $w$ has done to $x$, we usually like to say that $w$ is a function that sends $x$ to $w(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x}$, and say that the function that sends $x$ to $w^{-1}(x)=\frac 1 x-1$ is the *inverse* of $w$, precisely because $$w(w^{-1}(x))=w^{-1}(w(x))=x$$ that is, both function reverse what the other function has done to $x$.

Comment: So what do I do next? I solve the problem so that x = 0, what do I do next?

Comment: Plug and grind!  Not much grinding, though! ;)

Comment: @John Perfect. Now let $x=0$ in $$f\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)=2x-12$$ What happens?

Comment: so is the answer -12?

Comment: @John Do you mean $-12$?

Comment: yes sir sorry! typo!

Comment: @John Let me know if what I added is of any help.

Comment: Now we are very confused again, is the answer -12 or is the answer -10?

Comment: @John The answer is $-12$.

Comment: Ok thank you, that is what we all keep getting. Thank you for all of your help, I will try to wrap my head around everything you posted, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did, maybe this will help.

I figured that the modification of the input to produce a simple $x$ in the function output meant that $\frac 1 {1+x}(\text{something}) = x$.

It turns out that $\frac 1 {1+x} \frac {x(x-1)} 1=x$.

In the equation, replace $x$ with $x(x-1)$, then substitute for $x$:

$2(x^2-x)-12$

$2(1-1)-12$

$2\cdot 0-12$

$0-12$

$-12$

There's my crappy response.. :P

Comment: Substitute what for what? And are there supposed to be some equals signs or something in that sequence of expressions at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

First solve $y=\frac{1}{x+1}$ to get $x=\frac{1}{y}-1$. Then look at $f(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y}-1+1}) = f(y) = 2(\frac{1}{y}-1)-12 = \frac{2}{y}-14$. Note that this is valid as long as $y\neq 0$.

The equation above does not define $f$ for the argument $0$.

$f(1) = 2(\frac{1}{1}-1)-12 = -12$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace
$f(\frac{1}{x + 1}) = 2x - 12$
with
$f(y) = ?$.
I used $y$ instead of $x$
to, I hope, make things clearer.

So,
let $y = \frac{1}{x + 1}$.
We want to find the right side
($2x+1$)
in terms of $y$.
To do this,
we need to find
$x$ in terms of $y$.

This is just elementary algebra.
From 
$y = \frac{1}{x + 1}$,
$x+1 = \frac1{y}$
or
$x = \frac1{y}-1
=\frac{1-y}{y}
$.
Either expression 
for $x$ in terms of $y$
can be used.

From this,
$2x-12
=2(\frac1{y}-1)-12
=2\frac1{y}-2-12
=\frac{2}{y}-14
$.

Letting $y = 1$,
$f(1) 
=\frac{2}{1}-14
=-12
$.

Also,
putting $y = \frac12$,
$f(\frac12) 
=\frac{2}{\frac12}-14
= 4-14
=-10
$.
If you put $x=1$
in the original equation,
you also get
$f(\frac12)
= 2\cdot 1-12
=-10
$.

Note that
any expression in $x$
on the right side
 can be
converted into
an expression in $y$
this way.

Comment: Are you sure the answer is -10?

Comment: @John Marty is giving you $f(1)=-12$ and $f(1/2)=-10$.

Comment: Ohh okay now I get it, sorry I was confused. I did not see the $f(\frac{1}{2})$

Answer (score 1):

Draw the graph of $2x-12$
[image]

You are required to find the value of the function when the argument is "1", the argument is given as $\frac{1}{x+1} $

$\therefore \frac{1}{x+1}=1 \Rightarrow x=0$

the value of the function $2x-12$ is $\color{red} {-12}$ when $x=0$