# How does one solve a composite function problem if the function is limited by a domain.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm very confused and puzzled as to solve this problem:
$$f(\frac1{x+3}) = \frac1{2-5x}\text{ for } x > 1, \text{then } f(x) = ?.$$ I looked at some other answers that other users have given. For instance, [How do I solve this confusing Function problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488066/how-do-i-solve-this-confusing-function-problem). This definitely helped me better understand the problem, however I'm still kind of confused on how to come up with the answer since there is a domain associated with it. For now, I have done the following:

1. Set the function $\frac1{x+3}$ to a variable such as $u$.
2. Solved $u$ in terms of $x$: $x=\frac{1-u}u$
3. Let $y$ = $u$: $x=\frac{1-y}y$
4. Plugged $x=\frac{1-y}y$ into the function $\frac1{2-5x}$
5. got the function $\frac y{17y - 5}$

That was where I stopped. The two things that I need help are figuring out what $f(x)=?$, and knowing what the domain means to the answer. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you made a mistake, because $$u = \frac{1}{x+3} \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{1-3u}{u}$$ for $x\neq -3$ and $u\neq 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I just made a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two steps are good; however, you go a bit off the rails from step 3 onwards. Why introduce $y$? All that does is rename $u$, but $u$ is a perfectly fine label in its own right. Also in step 2, you didn't solve for $x$ correctly: if $\frac{1}{x+3}=u$, then $u(x+3)=1$, so $x=\frac{1}{u}-3 = \frac{1-3u}{u}$. You then want to substitute this for $x$ in the expression for $f(u)=f(\frac{1}{x+3})$. What you get is $\frac{1}{2-5x} = \frac{1}{2-5\frac{1-3u}{u}}=\frac{1}{\frac{2u-5+15u}{u}}=\frac{u}{17u-5}$

*Now* it's time to relabel $u$. Since the question wants you to find $f(x)$, simply replace all instances of $u$ with $x$. You get a final answer of $f(x)=\frac{x}{17x-5}$.

Addendum: I see you got the correct answer, which makes me think that your solution for $x$ is merely a typo; is that  correct? As for the domain of $f(x)$, you can deduce that in the following way: if the domain of $f(\frac{1}{x+3})$ is all $x\gt 1$ and $x=\frac{1-3u}{u}$, then $\frac{1-3u}{u}\gt 1$, which implies that $1-3u\gt u$, from which you can conclude that $\frac{1}{4}\gt u$. The domain of $f(x)$ is therefore all $x$ such that $x\lt \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: I was just following a mix of answers from that link that I included. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/488069/1220261 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/488069/1220261 were ones that I specifically followed. Also, for step 2, I just made a typo and forgot to include the 3. Thanks though, I still am wondering what the x > 1 means for this answer.

Comment: Haha you anticipated my edits it seems! Have another read, should clear up all your confusions :)

Comment: Thanks! now that I think about it, it makes more sense now. I'm in a math club, and this was a warmup question that was given. Anway, thank you for explaining it.